# Arbitrary response content types in Feathers

Tags: content-type, feathersjs

I have a custom service that must return data in CSV format.

I can't use a standard Express route, because I need Feathers' hooks on this endpoint.

I couldn't find an example of a Feathers service returning non-HTML, non-JSON data, and have found no way to specify a response content type.

Using `res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv')` before returning from the service method didn't work; the final `Content-Type` header was reset to `application/json`, even though the method's return value was a regular string.

How can I properly set arbitrary response content types in Feathers' custom service methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the response format like this:

```
const feathers = require('feathers');
const rest = require('feathers-rest');

const app = feathers();

function restFormatter(req, res) {
  res.format({
    'text/plain': function() {
      res.end(`The Message is: "${res.data.text}"`);
    }
  });
}

app.configure(rest(restFormatter));
```

The complete documentation can be found [here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/rest.html#appconfigurerestformatter).

Using your [own service specific middleware](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#custom-service-middleware) to send the response should also work.

Comment: I've seen that in the docs, but it's painfully unclear to me how that cooperates with the service middlewares to achieve the desired result. I think I'll go with the service-specific middleware here, just because I don't understand the restFormatter option. Also that looks like content-negotiation, when in fact I want to force a content-type; it's a download endpoint.

Comment: The service-specific middleware did the trick, thanks as usual ;)