# How to return non-json data in a response from feathers js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, feathersjs

I need to return a string without quotes in a response to a api request on a feathers js systems endpoint. I understand this should be possible using service specific middleware, but the documentation is not very clear on how to get one of these working within the feathers generated environment. Can someone provide an example of how this would work with the generated structure of the current feathers js system?

Ive tried stumbling through tearing apart the one example within the documentation, nothing i have tried has been successful or even worth mentioning here, i feel im a bit too confused by the documentation on this subject.

current output - "response"

output needs to be - response

Comment: Maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40169827/arbitrary-response-content-types-in-feathers) can be of some use?

Answer (score 0):

Service specific middleware can be added where `app.use('/servicename', service)` for your service is called (e.g. [here in the chat application messages service](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat/blob/master/src/services/messages/messages.service.js#L17)). It can then be used as documented:

```
app.use('/messages', createService(options), (req, res) => {
  // res.data is the response
  res.end('Got data: ' + res.data.text);
});
```

It is also possible to register a [global formatter](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#appconfigureexpressrestformatter) that applies to all responses.